# How to call DotNetNuke's HTML module dynamically

Tags: dotnetnuke

So I have a module that allows a registered user to enter their subject matter. The feature I would like to add is when he posts the subject, the webpage renders the subject with a blank html module underneath it.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you really want to use the HTML Editor, not the HTML module, check out my DNNSimpleArticle module for an example

http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20228#83722

The basics are

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx" %>

<dnn:TextEditor ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="300px" />
```

Comment: thanks Chris! I take it the reason why the info from the textboxes and the texteditor are blank everytime I hit settings is because that information is not saved or being saved in the database. Am I right on that?

Comment: That is likely part of the reason, check the ascx.cs file in the source control I linked to earlier for how to access and set the values

Comment: is there a place where I can get a list of all the dnn element tags? 
(ex. <dnn:texteditor> or <dnn:nav>)

Comment: Unfortunately there's not a great place to get them all, other than opening up the Controls folder and looking in there.